# Installing on Iphone gets stuck after setting up firebase_messaging

Tags: ios, flutter

Following the Readme of the https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging I set up the IOS and Android firebase. On Android it works but when I try to install the app by running "flutter run" on IOS, it gets stuck at installing it and I can't open it.

[image]

After I took the screenshot a new line appeared under "Installing and launching",  "Configuring firebase for this app..." (or something like this).

I tried deleting the pods and set up again.
I tried deleting the app so it can be installed again.
I that at some point during the "Installing and launching..." the app tries to open but closes back immediately. Is it a crash? How do I get some sort of info regarding this? Thank you!

Comment: local messages plugins are know to cause conflicts with `firebase_messaging`. Try removing all local messaging dependencies if you have any and try again.

Answer (score 0):

check these two things:

1. For iOS, the `firebase_messaging` functionality only works on real devices, it doesn't work on the simulator. (it does work in Android emulator)
2. Run `open -a xcode ios/` and try to build the app there (⌘R), there will be more details on possible errors, specially regarding filling in the Signing section. Even if it's not signing, you will find out what it is, and after fixing it, the flutter cli will resume running without issues.

[image: XCode Runner Signing tab]

Comment: I figured it out in the end. I was deploying on a real device and my sign in was fine. Anyway, thank you for letting me know how I could see the logs of other errors and I didn't put the GoogleServices-Info.plist in the correct path. Thank you!